# Error al compilar funciones con paso de puntero como parámetro

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> paso-por-referencia.cpp:(.text+0x21): referencia a `std::cout' sin definir
> paso-por-referencia.cpp:(.text+0x26): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' sin definir
> paso-por-referencia.cpp:(.text+0x30): referencia a `std::ostream::operator<<(int)' sin definir
> paso-por-referencia.cpp:(.text+0x35): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' sin definir...`
> ```

cuando quiero compilar el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcion(int *q);

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p;

    a = 100;
    p = &a;
    cout << "variable a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "variable *p: " << *p << endl;

    funcion(&a);

    cout << "variable a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "variable *p: " << *p << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void funcion (int *q)
{
    *q += 50;
     q++;
}
```

Y no se por qué, lo estoy compilando en linux con gcc y extensión cpp.

Comment: ¿ Puedes indicar **exactamente** como llamas al compilador ? La orden exacta que ejecutas para compilar.

Comment: El código [funciona en gcc y clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qXihFe6U3WrAzc2b).

Answer (score -2):

iostream no es una librería estándar de gcc, tienes que compilar con g++ tu archivo cpp.

Intenta

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
```

o también si quieres hacerlo con gcc:

```
gcc main.cpp -lstdc++ -o main.o
```

Saludos, espero te ayude.